# How to resolve "aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a certain data which has a value of 'Share 02015'. I split the data and incremented the the numeric part with the max value. Then when I try to update query, It throws following error.

> aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

The query I'm using is

```
UPDATE dbo.Ledgers
SET LedgerName = 'Share 00' +(CAST( MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(LedgerName, CHARINDEX(' ', LedgerName) + 1, 6) AS int)+1)AS nvarchar))
WHERE LedgerName = 'Share 00877';
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in error message, you cannot use `MAX` or any other aggregate function in update `SET` list

Try using `CTE` to update

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT new_LedgerName = 'Share 00' + ( Cast(Max(Cast(Substring(LedgerName, Charindex(' ', LedgerName) + 1, 6) AS INT)
                                                         + 1)AS NVARCHAR) ),
                LedgerName
         FROM   dbo.Ledgers
         WHERE  LedgerName = 'Share 00877'
         GROUP BY LedgerName)
UPDATE cte
SET    LedgerName = new_LedgerName
```